# C# HttpClient request fails to scrape (both on System.Net and Windows.Web http requests)

Tags: c#, http, filter, httprequest, httpclient

I am trying to **scrape** the news off this site: https://www.livescore.com/soccer/news/

```
using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                                 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident / 6.0)");
                using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(pageURL)))
                using (Windows.Web.Http.IHttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        }
```

I see that I am getting a `response` containing `Your browser is out of date or some of its features are disabled`
I moved to `Windows.Web` to add `certificates` since I am on `UWP` and tried adding the following `certificates`

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.IncompleteChain);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.WrongUsage);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.RevocationInformationMissing);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.RevocationFailure);
```

but I am still getting the same `response` from the server.
Any idea how to bypass this?

Edit: They do have the old server, unsecured, http://www.livescore.com/, where I guess I can **scrape** everything but news aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the user-agent string. you are telling to site that the browser are you using is Internet Explorer 10.
Look this page http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer and try to use the user agent for internet Explorer 11 (before make this open the page from your ie11 browser to check that function properly)

Comment: This is not a trick. The website is telling you that the browser that the site see is too old. This appends because, with the user agent parameter, you are telling to site that the invocation is made by a internet Explorer 10 browser. If you change the user agent parameter you tell to site that the request is made by an internet explorer 11and the site think that the browser is updated and support all features